# How to remove "NULL" strings from a JSON object in sails.js using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, sails.js

The JSON Object is as shown below. I want to remove all the keys with the value NULL. Also, if after removing the pair, if the entry is blank then that should also be removed. I have tried looking for a script that performs the required task but I haven't been successful at it. Keep in mind, it is a NULL string and not an object. I need to implement this is sails.js so Javascript is the most preferred language.

```
var JSONobj ={  "regex_attributes": {
"matching attributes": {
  "transaction_amount": {
    "matching_position": "1"
  },
  "total_amount_due": {
    "matching_position": "NULL"
  },
  "transaction_date": {
    "matching_position": "NULL",
    "date_format": "NULL"
  },
  "current_credit": {
    "matching_position": "NULL"
  },
  "available_credit": {
    "matching_position": "NULL"
  },
  "date_posted": {
    "matching_position": "NULL",
    "date_format": "NULL"
  },
  "merchant": {
    "matching_position": "NULL"
  },
  "bill_date": {
    "matching_position": "NULL",
    "date_format": "NULL"
  },
  "bill_due_date": {
    "matching_position": "NULL",
    "date_format": "NULL"
  },
  "bill_amount": {
    "matching_position": "NULL"
  },
  "account_number_ending": {
    "matching_position": "2"
  },
  "balance_date": {
    "matching_position": "NULL",
    "date_format": "NULL"
  },
  "available_balance": {
    "matching_position": "NULL"
  }
},
"additional_processing": [     //Array
  {
    "sms_sender_name": "NULL",
    "type_of_account_to_find": "NULL",
    "attribute": "description",
    "operation": "pre_add",
    "pre_add_1": "Credit"
  }
],
"account_details": {
  "credit_or_debit": "CREDIT",
  "type_of_transaction": "INT",
  "type_of_account": "SAVINGS",
  "type_of_action": "TRANSACTION",
  "bills_account_type": "NULL"
}
```

}
}

Comment: Where did you get that JSON from?

Comment: It's part of a bigger project. But now I need to delete the NULL strings and I'm stuck at that.

Comment: Can you change whatever generates that JSON instead? Because that would be a much better idea.

Comment: Okay I'll try that instead of this. But if you get a solution, do let me know. Thanks.

Comment: It's always best to try and fix the problem as far upstream as you possibly can :-)

Answer (score 0):

I agree that it is better to fix the source, but the source even if formatted correctly will still have the NULLs (just not as strings) and since your question addressed removing those as well I would just use lodash or underscore to pop out the bad information. This is an example. You should play around with it to get it just right. Sails includes lodash as a dependency, otherwise to practice outside of sails just make sure to include the lodash library and refer to the docs if neccessary https://lodash.com/docs

```
_.mixin({
  cleanObject: function(o) {
    _.each(o, function(v, k) {
      if(k === 'NULL') {
        delete o[k];
      }
      else if(!v) {
        delete o[k];
      }
    });
    return o;
  }
});

var cleanedUp = _.cleanObject(JSONobj);
```

I can understand that sometimes you get bad information from the source. I have had to patch into plenty of legacy systems in my time.

Comment: Then you should post your method as an answer so others can benefit as you have.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(var key in JSONObj.regex_attributes.matching_attributes){
    for (var key2 in JSONObj.regex_attributes.matching_attributes[key])
    {
      var val = JSONObj.regex_attributes.matching_attributes[key][key2]
      if (val == 'NULL')
          delete JSONObj.regex_attributes.matching_attributes[key][key2]
    }
    }


  for (var key in JSONObj.regex_attributes.matching_attributes){
    var k=Object.keys(JSONObj.regex_attributes.matching_attributes[key]).length
    if (k==0){
      delete JSONObj.regex_attributes.matching_attributes[key]
    }
  }

  for (var key in JSONObj.regex_attributes){
    var k=Object.keys(JSONObj.regex_attributes[key]).length
    if (k==0){
      delete JSONObj.regex_attributes[key]
    }
  }

  var count2=0
  for (var key in JSONObj.regex_attributes.additional_processing[0]) {

      var val = JSONObj.regex_attributes.additional_processing[0][key];
      if (val == 'NULL'){
        delete JSONObj.regex_attributes.additional_processing[0][key]
        count2=count2+1
      }
  }

  if(count2==6){
      delete JSONObj.regex_attributes.additional_processing
  }

  var count3=0
  for (var key in JSONObj.regex_attributes.account_details) {

      var val = JSONObj.regex_attributes.account_details[key];
      if (val == 'NULL'){
        delete JSONObj.regex_attributes.account_details[key]
        count3=count3+1
      }

  }
  if (count3==5){
    delete JSONObj.regex_attributes.account_details
  }
```